# Spinning Solar Cells at 50 hz make a pure sine wave?

Tags: solar-cell, physical-design

What would be the out put of the solar panels spinning towards the sun? Ideal conditions would be o gravity in a vacuum tube or space.

Comment: Would probably be easy to spin a cover/shade on the solar panel.

Comment: It would be a horribly inefficient design spending most of its time away from optimal perpendicular aim at the sun.  It would result in poor efficacy and power output.  What made you think this works better than what is currently being used with solar tracking?

Comment: It would not be a pure sine wave because the response of the solar panel to varying levels of radiation is not perfectly linear. It would be a reasonably sinusoidal wave, but not an esoterically pure sinusoid. For that, you probably can't do much better than some type of synchronous generator. (unless you use feedback and electronic control)

Comment: It depends on the capacitance of the cell, if is to high this will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you had a double sided panel, you would obviously have half the power since one side is always in the shade.

The side that is in the sun would present its face area orthogonal to the sun in a half sine wave. Assuming linearity, that is, that surface reflections does not steel energy at acute angles, that means you only get 0.637. average for the half cycle.

As such, in total, your output would be reduced to 0.3135 of what you would get from just pointing the panels directly at the sun.

An invertor on the other hand would work closer to 0.95.

It WOULD be a cool thing to see though.

**EDIT**

This really is a theoretical idea though.

In reality, getting the thing to spin at 50Hz, which is 3,000rpm, would also be a challenge. The forces involved would tear it apart if it has any significant diameter. Long and thin would also have it's own set of issues like excessive vibration and resonant oscillations that would also tear the solar panels apart.

Comment: How to get them to run in sequence? Would they not last longer too since it is the UV is mostly depletes the cells? just add more cells in series to bring it up to 120 volts while spinning.

Comment: It is a really bad concept for a power source.

Comment: @Procreator nope. Sure it might last three times longer, but it needs to be three times larger, so it is a wash. As for running them in sequence, it would be a simple commutator to pull power from the side facing the sun. One side would be wired in reverse to get the negative voltage cycle.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 yup it's horrible..

Comment: Mechanical wear from vibrations would probably be worse than the diminished UV you're receiving. I don't understand what you(OP) have against inverters. Every SMPS has part of one inside them..